# Simplifying for loops and if statements

Tags: python

I have this to define the moves of the computer in my tic tac toe game, and it seems quite crazy to me, is there a way to simplify this into fewer lines of code? I have a limit on memory space, I am doing a project on making a tic tac toe game, the winner of this project is the one with the least amount of code, and yes I am new to python, which is likely quite obvious to you.

```
def Defense():
global ComputerChoice
global RandomChoice
global Defending
RandomChoice = False

Index1Win = any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[2,3],[4,7],[5,9]])
Index2Win = any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[1,3],[5,8]])
Index3Win = any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[1,2],[6,9],[5,7]])
Index4Win = any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[1,7],[5,6]])
Index5Win = any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[1,9],[3,7],[4,6],[2,8]])
Index6Win = any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[4,5],[3,9]])
Index7Win = any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[1,4],[8,9],[5,3]])
Index8Win = any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[2,5],[7,9]])
Index9Win = any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[1,5],[7,8],[6,3]])

if Index1Win == True and Availble[0] == 1:
    ComputerChoice = 1
    Defending = True
elif Index2Win == True and Availble[1] == 2:
    ComputerChoice = 2
    Defending = True
elif Index3Win == True and Availble[2] == 3:
    ComputerChoice = 3
    Defending = True
elif Index4Win == True and Availble[3] == 4:
    ComputerChoice = 4
    Defending = True
elif Index5Win == True and Availble[4] == 5:
    ComputerChoice = 5
    Defending = True
elif Index6Win == True and Availble[5] == 6:
    ComputerChoice = 6
    Defending = True
elif Index7Win == True and Availble[6] == 7:
    ComputerChoice = 7
    Defending = True
elif Index8Win == True and Availble[7] == 8:
    ComputerChoice = 8
    Defending = True
elif Index9Win == True and Availble[8] == 9:
    ComputerChoice = 9
    Defending = True
else:
    RandomChoice = True
    Defending = False
```

Comment: The only variable between all these cases is a number. You can use one variable to derive this number for each case. You just need to use a list instead of `Index_Win` to do this easily: `if IndexWin[i + 1] and Available[i] == i + 1: ComputerChoice = i + 1`…

Comment: Having said that, there would probably be more appropriate algorithms to start with, but that'd be the first step…

Comment: *"I have a limit on memory space."* — What kind of limit is that that reducing these handful of lines would help…?!

Comment: @deceze Sorry I should have explained more in-depth.

Answer (score 2):

```
indexlist=[Index1Win,Index2Win,Index3Win,Index4Win,Index5Win,Index6Win,Index7Win,Index8Win,Index9Win]

for i, j in enumerate(indexlist):
  if j and Available[i]==i+1:
    ComputerChoice = 1
    Defending = True
    break

 else:
    RandomChoice = True
    Defending = False
```

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a try, I converted Index to a list and then just iterate over that and if the current index is true, set the Choice accordingly. If no index is true, the loop finishes without tripping the break and the else clause will get called.

```py
def Defense():
global ComputerChoice
global RandomChoice
global Defending
RandomChoice = False
Index = []
Index.append(any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[2,3],[4,7],[5,9]]))
Index.append(any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[1,3],[5,8]]))
Index.append(any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[1,2],[6,9],[5,7]]))
Index.append(any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[1,7],[5,6]]))
Index.append(any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[1,9],[3,7],[4,6],[2,8]]))
Index.append(any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[4,5],[3,9]]))
Index.append(any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[1,4],[8,9],[5,3]]))
Index.append(any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[2,5],[7,9]]))
Index.append(any(all(n in PlayerList for n in win) for win in [[1,5],[7,8],[6,3]]))

for i, idx in enumerate(Index):
    if idx and Available[i] == i+1:
        ComputerChoice = Available[i]
        Defending = True
        break
else:
    RandomChoice = True
    Defending = False
```